# Boot 2 Gecko Development Kit

Tags: web-applications, firefox-os

I am looking into Mozilla's Boot 2 Gecko Os for development of Web app, that would expose the capabilities of hardware and system level access (Camera, File system, contact ) as well.

Can any one suggest which is the suitable and preferred development IDE should be used and From where i can get the Development Kit got Boot 2 Gecko ?

Thanks,
Rakesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox OS (B2G) apps are just Web apps on steroids, so you can use a standard web development tool set to create apps for it. There are no external dependencies (like the Android and iOS SDKs), it's simply HTML that can access things like device orientation, camera and the local filesystem through a set of JavaScript APIs.

You can find extensive HTML, CSS, JavaScript and DOM documentation on the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/), and there's also [a section dedicated to Firefox OS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS).

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard web development tool to develop,
and use Firefox build-in/Firebug debugging tools to test Firefox OS (B2G).
Though you may need physical device to test some features (Camera, accelerator...,etc).

1. You can get Firefox Nightly (Aurora)

   Firefox Nightly http://nightly.mozilla.org/
2. then install Firefox-os Simulator add-on

   Firefox-os Simulator https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firefox-os-simulator/
3. run Simulator from tools/developer/Firefox OS Simulator
4. prepare a local or remote web server to host your web pages.
5. open your page in simulator's browser and see how it looks

Done. You can follow the web developer guide from Firefox MarketPlace to improve your web page(s) to act and perform as an elegant app
https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/docs/web_developers